# Is there confirmation blocks in Proof-of-Stake Blockchain?

Tags: proof-of-work

When I'm reading literature about proof-of-stake blockchain, I found that it seems there is no concept about confirmation blocks (which is used to confirm a posted transaction is indeed honestly generated and in bitcoin we need 6 confirmation blocks that is enough). However, my question is that why we don't need confirmation blocks in Proof-of-Stake blockchain like Proof-of-Work blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

For a proof-of-work blockchain, say Bitcoin, the confirmation length is 6, just to make sure any adversary doesn't create any additional blocks and make a new fork that's longer. That's possible because all you need is more computation, and no proof of *identity*.

However, in proof-of-stake blockchain protocols, you often need to provide a new block with some kind of proof that you are eligible to propose the new block. This instantly creates a confirmed block because for a particular slot, another party cannot create a valid block and proof later in time.

Take a look at the Algorand protocol for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the bitcoin case, you need to wait for confirmation of 6 blocks because many miners are involved, some of which might be attackers. But in the case of proof of stack there is no competition and only one who is eligible to add a block, and no attackers.